# How to invert the rows with columns in this MDX Query?

Tags: mdx, dashboard, saiku

How can I change this `MDX` query (get from Saiku) so that "anno" (year) and `measures` are put in the column?

MDX Query:

```
WITH 
  SET [~ROWS_Regime Ricovero_Regime Ricovero.Regime Ricovero] AS 
    {[Regime Ricovero].[Degenza ordinaria]} 
  SET [~ROWS_Anno_Anno.Anno] AS 
    {[Anno].[Anno].MEMBERS} 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Numero di Ricoveri]
     ,[Measures].[Dimessi 0-1 Giorno]
     ,[Measures].[Dimessi > di 1 Giorno]
     ,[Measures].[Giornate di Degenza]
     ,[Measures].[Degenza Media]
     ,[Measures].[Occupazione Media (Percentuale)]
     ,[Measures].[Indice di Rotazione]
     ,[Measures].[Presenti Medi Giornaliari]
     ,[Measures].[Numero di Interventi]
     ,[Measures].[DRG Peso]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    NonEmptyCrossJoin
    (
      [~ROWS_Regime Ricovero_Regime Ricovero.Regime Ricovero]
     ,[~ROWS_Anno_Anno.Anno]
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Cubo Virtuale Report Dati Attività];
```

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ6SH.jpg)

In practice, I would like to see this table vertically and not horizontally.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can swap ROWS and COLUMNS however you like.

This configuration should be more vertical:

```
WITH 
  SET [~ROWS_Regime Ricovero_Regime Ricovero.Regime Ricovero] AS 
    {[Regime Ricovero].[Degenza ordinaria]} 
  SET [~ROWS_Anno_Anno.Anno] AS 
    {[Anno].[Anno].MEMBERS} 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
   [~ROWS_Anno_Anno.Anno]
   ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
     CrossJoin(
     [~ROWS_Regime Ricovero_Regime Ricovero.Regime Ricovero]
    ,
    {
      [Measures].[Numero di Ricoveri]
     ,[Measures].[Dimessi 0-1 Giorno]
     ,[Measures].[Dimessi > di 1 Giorno]
     ,[Measures].[Giornate di Degenza]
     ,[Measures].[Degenza Media]
     ,[Measures].[Occupazione Media (Percentuale)]
     ,[Measures].[Indice di Rotazione]
     ,[Measures].[Presenti Medi Giornaliari]
     ,[Measures].[Numero di Interventi]
     ,[Measures].[DRG Peso]
    }
    )
      ON ROWS
FROM [Cubo Virtuale Report Dati Attività];
```

Comment: The MDX Query works in saiku, but the table component gives an error.
There is another way to write the same query?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be the "*"?

Comment: "*" is the modern way to write CrossJoin - try swapping back to CrossJoin

Comment: Ok, that was not the problem.
Thank you very much the same, but despite being just what I wanted, does not read the query.

Comment: what does this mean "but despite being just what I wanted, does not read the query" ...does it mean I answered your question?

Comment: I use two tools in which I enter the query, in one of these, it works perfectly, but the same query in the other gives me an error. While the query published in the question by me worked.

Comment: ok - well it might be similar behaviour to SSRS - in that tool each measure has to be in a seperate column! (there is no choice about this in SSRS)